# How to split the nested list in two parts?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

I am having a nested list of size M x N.

```
 [['12', '23', '56'],
 ['1', '4', '5'],
 ['67', '78', '98']]
```

I want to split it in below format:

```
List 1 = [['12','23'],
['1','4'],
['67','78']]
and List 2 = ['56','5','98']
```

Comment: Can you please share with us what you've tried so far?

Comment: Downvotes, downvotes everywhere

Answer (score 3):

This is one way to generically remove the last item from the all of the lists in `lsts` into a new list `removed`:

```
lsts = [['12', '23', '56'],
        ['1', '4', '5'],
        ['67', '78', '98']]

removed = [lst.pop() for lst in lsts]

print(lsts, removed)
```

Output:

```
[['12', '23'], ['1', '4'], ['67', '78']] ['56', '5', '98']
```

http://ideone.com/xphb3P

Comment: Do you have any idea what is happening?

Comment: Someone having god complex with the downvote option. All the solutions are correct and should not have downvotes

Comment: There must be at least two of them

Comment: juniorcompressor, some people don't like others answering bad questions. Frankly? I can understand.

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved with list comprehensions:

```
a = [['12', '23', '56'],
     ['1', '4', '5'],
     ['67', '78', '98']]
l1 = [s[:2] for s in  a]
l2 = [s[2] for s in a]
```

`l1` contains `[['12', '23'], ['1', '4'], ['67', '78']]`

`l2` conatins `['56', '5', '98']`

Comment: My answer provides the solution to the question, please leave a comment to explain the downvote.